# Angular 2 implicit input with Pure Pipes

Tags: javascript, angular

We are in the process of making a translation pipe using Angular 2. The expected template syntax should be something similar to this: 
`{{'lbl_translate': translate}}`

But, as per the documentation,

> Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the
>   input value

So this would not update when the language is changed in the application.

The question is, is it possible to pass in the language to this pipe implicitly as another input? Without having to explicitly specify it as follows: `{{'lbl_translate': translate:'en'}}`

Would it be possible to pass the 'en' value implicitly? Is there a better way of triggering this change?

Comment: There is no way. If the value or parameters passed to a pure pipe don't change, Angular won't execute it.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel and not use ng2-translate instead? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate

Comment: @NicoVanBelle that is how to learn and code i guess.

Comment: ng2-translate uses impure pipes which will impact on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Günter, it is not possible to fire off a pure pipe without changing the inputs. This is by design so that the pure pipes stay performent.

We went with using impure pipes for our purposes as has been done in the ng2-translate package. This does have a toll on performance but works well for the needs. But it is important to keep the function as simple as possible inside the pipe to keep the application running at an acceptable speed.